# High performance graph for showing FFT in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es, core-animation, fft

I am writing an app which displays several FFT graphs in real time. I have been doing the drawing using views, but this is starting to really eat my CPU power as UIViews draw their contents on the CPU. I am looking for a solution to draw the FFT graph which will move the operation from the CPU of the ipad to the GPU.

So far the solutions that I have thought of seems to be either trying to use CALayers and making each data point in the graph (512 of them) an individual layer, or trying to use OpenGL to draw my graph, which is wayyyyyy out of my depth.... I know this is a vague question, but I was hoping that someone here would have a more clever idea of how to draw my FFT graphs on the GPU and free up some processor power.

Comment: Have you measured this to verify that drawing is the limited factor and not for example the FFT calculations? What performance are you getting from your existing solution? How are you currently drawing the graphs? Do you need to render all 512 data points (i.e. is the view at least 512 points wide)? How (and how often) are you triggering the redraws?

Comment: If you haven't made a measurement yet. The combination of "Core Animation", "Time Profiler", and possibly also "CPU Monitor" is probably a good start to get a sense of the current situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw large complex 2D graphs rapidly (30 or 60 fps) on iOS devices, one likely has to use Open GL to keep the most of any graph rendering on the GPU.  Any Core Graphics or raw bitmap drawing into UIViews or CALayers will require not only lots of CPU cycles, but uploading large textures to the GPU texture cache, which will hit a bandwidth limit.

Comment: I suspected the answer would be Open GL, but I was really intimidated by the learning curve for it. I ended up finding a good tutorial at [link](http://www.200monkeys.com/index.php/2012/12/28/opengl-es-2-0-tutorial-getting-started/) with a corresponding git project that enabled me to get started by just drawing a line. From there, it was fairly easy to add more points to the line and create something resembling an fft graph. Filling it with random values I am able to easily graph at 30 FPS using almost none of my CPU in a quick test. Thanks for the advice!